# How to use gradleW in order to get a signed apk from command line?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to have a jenkins job to automatically compile and sign my APK file with a keystore I have in a folder. I've tried this:

```
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
SET ANDROID_HOME=E:\androidsdk
SET PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%;%ANDROID_HOME%
SET ZIPALIGN="%ANDROID_HOME%\build-tools\23.0.3\zipalign"

echo %cd%

gradlew assembleDebug & "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jarsigner" -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore key-jenkins\MyKey.jks -storepass rusavon app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unsigned.apk Mypassword& %ZIPALIGN% -v 4 app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unsigned.apk app\build\outputs\apk\debug-r%SVN_REVISION%.apk
```

but it's not working. (it used to work in other project where gradle was used instead of gradlew).

Answer (score 6):

You should consider adding build types and signing config in build.gradle and then running the ./gradlew assembleRelease

It should build a signed apk.

Make following changes to build.gradle.

```
buildTypes {
        // Debug Configuration
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = true
            debuggable true
        }
        // Release Configuration
        release {
            testCoverageEnabled = false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
```

and then have these signing configs :

```
 signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("xx-key.keystore")
            storePassword "xx123"
            keyAlias "xxxx"
            keyPassword "xx123"
        }
        release {
            keyAlias 'xxxx'
            keyPassword 'xx123'
            storeFile file('xxxxxx-Key.keystore')
            storePassword 'xx12'
        }
    }
```

> Run command to generate signed apk : ./gradlew assembleRelease

Comment: `Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'release' for SigningConfig container of type org.gradle.api.internal.FactoryNamedDomainObjectContainer.
`